# What advantages/disadvantages would Neanderthals have in a 16th Century military conflict?

Tags: biology, military, history, anthropology

Homo Neanderthalensis is a Homo species that went extinct 40,000 years ago. Let's say that Neanderthals made it to the Americas and was isolated on that continent until Spanish colonization. Let's also say that the Neanderthals were able to quickly copy the military technology of the Spanish. What advantages would the Neanderhtals have against Homo Sapiens in warfare?

Neanderthals had big heads with even more brain capacity than humans. That could mean that they not only have thick skulls but could be just as smart if not smarter than Homo Sapiens. In addition, Neanderthals were less sexually dimorphic than humans so their women can fight almost as well as their men could. Neanderthals mostly spoke through sign language which would make communication visual rather than audible. I don't think diseases would harm the Neanderthals like it did the Native Americans due to them being a different species.

Comment: Neanderthals are known to have been interfertile with modern humans, because many modern humans of European descent have some identifiable Neanderthal genes. If they're that close, many of the same diseases will affect them.

Comment: There is no reason to believe neanderthal could not speak, there vocal track looks just like ours. The main disadvantage Neanderthals had was living in much smaller groups which means they can't copy Spanish tech even if they did know how it was done, they can't mobilize enough man power or specialized labor. heck native Americans could not copy Spanish tech what makes you think Neanderthals will. neanderthal lost to humans when they had the same stone age tech because of their small group size later tech will only make this difference larger.

Comment: [Fascinating video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o589CAu73UM) from a combination of scientists, vocal experts and an actor to demonstrate (from the BBC and Guildhall School of Music and Drama). They sounded silly and shrill by all accounts. @John

Comment: Neanderthals were a diffrent species or were not a different species, depending on whom you ask. Traditionally, in the 1970s, western capitalist paleontologists classified them as a different species, *H. neandethalensis*, while good eastern communist paleontologists classified them as a subspecies, *H. sapiens neanderthalensis*. And they did not go extinct: the people of Europe and Asia are their descendants. (And the idea that they commuinicated by sign language instead of speaking like normal humans is strange; they *were* fully human humans.)

Comment: Let's change the historical setup: in the 13th century the Mongols invaded what are now Russia and Ukraine. The average Russian is visibly taller and bigger than the average Mongol. Who won, and who paid tribute to whom for several centuries?

Comment: I'm curious about your assertion that spoken language makes modern humans "audibly biased". Humans are much more known for their visual senses - which are remarkably keen for mammals, especially where color and pattern are concerned - than their so-so hearing.

Comment: @Cadence I said human communication is audibly based not humans in general. There is a reason why many countries have official spoken languages but no country has an official sign language.

Comment: @ITM_Coder I changed the sentence containing "visually biased", which means something else. I won't join the close  vote, interesting  question..

Comment: Neanderthals couldn't defeat primitive homo sapiens what makes you think giving sapiens a technology edge would make a difference?

Comment: Should have really included related [different hominid vs 19th century](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/232341/what-advantages-disadvantages-would-homo-erectus-have-in-a-19th-century-military)

Comment: It would depend on how they were used.

They would be stronger/more suitable as shock troops. Perhaps not every ‘normal’ human might be aware of them and, when suddenly confronted with them, might pause or even get spooked.

Beyond that, not that much. They are not that much different from ‘normal’ humans and would die as easily to a sword, spear, bolt, bullet or arrow like any other.

Perhaps as a labour force? They could work the forges/finish constructions a bit faster due to their stronger builds?

Comment: It really sounds like you answered your own question? Maybe you should just reword it as an [tag:internal-consistency] question, test if your assumptions jive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is an interesting one, but difficult to answer due to the complexity involved in such a hypothetical situation. There were certain steps which needed to be taken to move homo sapiens from small bands of tribal hunter gatherers to that of a region-spanning civilization. The rise of agriculture and domestication of animals allowed humans to transition from a transitory lifestyle to a stationary one. An abundance of foodstuff then allowed for more free time to develop other areas such as pottery for storing food, alcohol production, and improved building methods. A stationary lifestyle also allowed for the development of infrastructure which leads to other developments. Metallurgy requires forges and smithies which contain large and heavy tools and devices.

You will need to pick a timeframe of when your hypothetical Neanderthals moved into the Americas. As their extinction was give or take 40k years ago, it would need to be prior to this time. If their emergence was at least 200k years ago (https://www.britannica.com/topic/Neanderthal), then we can go one of two ways with their divergence. Either early Neanderthals transitioned as a group in their entirety to the Americas, leaving Europe and Asia free for future homo sapiens, or a group split off from the parent group to colonize the Americas separately at a future date. If Neanderthals moved over as a whole, and left early enough, there wouldn’t be any left to interbreed with humans. This would allow for further genetic drift prior to their eventual meeting.

On your hypothetical Earth, let’s figure out a way for the Neanderthals to migrate to the Americas. According to (https://www.thoughtco.com/bering-strait-and-the-land-bridge-170084), most of the Bering Land Bridge was exposed 60-25k years ago. That gives us an initial Americas transition date by Neanderthals of 60k years ago, 20k before their Euro/Asian extinction. As boats had been invented as far back as 800k years ago (https://www.marineinsight.com/maritime-history/when-were-boats-invented/) we will give our traveling Neanderthals the boating/rafting technology needed to cross into the Americas and down the coastline. By the time their overseas cousins are going the way of the dinosaurs, the American Neanderthals would have likely spread throughout both continents.

As a hunter gatherer lifestyle often demands smaller family groups, we can have the Neanderthals discover agriculture at a certain point. Homo sapiens developed agriculture around 12k years ago. If small tribal groups are more instinctually ingrained in Neanderthals, then it might be better to have them develop agriculture prior to homo sapiens as to give them time to adopt such a lifestyle. So, 20k years ago, your Neanderthals invent agriculture, but it spreads slowly throughout both continents. Their population increases, but instead of forming into larger city states, they might have smaller cities with limited trade developing between them. Many groups might continue their migratory lifestyle of traveling. As their diet was meat heavy (https://www.britannica.com/topic/Neanderthal/Genetics), there would likely be domestication of native wildlife such as buffalo and possibly even woolly mammoth.

Unless you change history in your world, the first interaction between homo sapiens and the American Neanderthals would be around 5-3k BCE when homo sapiens crossed the land bridge to settle in North America. Perhaps the homo sapiens simply interbred and were absorbed by the Neanderthals, adding their increased instinct to socialize into Neanderthal society. This could be the turning point for Neanderthal civilization, when it changes from smaller isolated towns into a more interconnected society. Increased interconnectivity will increase trade, which increases the odds in the discovery of the wheel. Trade across civilizations causes the development of writing for the purposes of tracking goods and taxes. Ideas will also flow across borders more easily.

The ability to quickly copy Spanish military technology means that they will have already discovered metallurgy, and be somewhat heavily into the iron age. Their history of warfare, or lack thereof, would determine their level of weapons technology. They would need a certain level of understanding to be able to reverse-engineer newly discovered technology. The Spanish still wore armor and carried swords as well as firearms. The Neanderthals would need to figure out how to copy the gunpowder formula, or maybe force a captive to divulge it. Denser body types will likely translate into increased difficulty swimming and potentially limit their boating technology to coastal trading and fishing craft. If drowning is significantly more likely for Neanderthals, they will likely have an instinctual fear of deep water, which would hinder naval development.

From a purely genetic standpoint, the larger brains are thought to contribute to better vision and motor control (https://www.history.com/topics/pre-history/neanderthals), which would not make them any smarter than homo sapiens. If we assume an intelligence level similar to that of homo sapiens, then you would have a species which has better than average physical characteristics and few other drawbacks. Stronger bodies with denser bones would decrease the risk of breaking bones. Increased strength would allow for bows with heavier pull weights and thus more impact when firing arrows. Naturally increased muscle mass could allow for longer hours of work or fighting before fatigue sets in. Heavier armor could be worn, providing more protection. Larger/heavier firearms could be carried and used. This could allow Neanderthal firearms to potentially out perform Spanish firearms. With better eyesight and longer ranged firearms, they could stand a decent chance at defending their lands. This would imbalance the scales, allowing Neanderthals to cause more harm to invading humans while taking fewer injuries.

The Spanish also used tribal rivalries to pit natives against each other to help facilitate their invasion. Neanderthals being so different from homo sapiens might preclude such a tactic. If Neanderthals are less aggressive towards each other than homo sapiens, then there is a good chance that their city states will come to each other’s aid should the need arise. This could hurt them if their initial reaction is to flee instead of fighting against the Spanish. It would be difficult to overcome a genetic predisposition against violence. If Neanderthals either have a fear of deep water or lack a significant naval presence, the Spanish could clear and utilize large islands as landing points for their forces prior to mainland invasion. Such a scenario might result in the Spanish taking over the islands, but remaining unable to make significant headway on the mainland if facing a strong or unified Neanderthal presence.

If Neanderthals have retained their less social nature, and remained as smaller isolated city states, they might fail to put up a strong resistance force of sufficient numbers to overcome Spanish forces. Instead, the Spanish would simply clear the continent one city at a time. Once they have a few decent sized cities they could out reproduce the Neanderthals and field armies significantly more massive. If human DNA has mixed with the Neanderthal DNA to a significant degree, it is a near certainty that human specific viruses could infect both populations (as many European groups had Neanderthal DNA). Lacking this mixing, it is slightly more likely that Neanderthals would pass their viruses to the European invaders but be alien enough to resist European viruses. The fact that humans and Neanderthals could create viable offspring makes it a near certainty that any virus which could infect one group could infect the other.

The physical differences are not that extreme, and gunpowder is the great equalizer. The biggest difference would be the social/mental structure of Neanderthals and how their civilizations operate. Getting them to the technological point where they could utilize 16th century technology assumes certain developments have happened. Those developments were less about physical strength and more about mentality or necessity. The Chinese had gunpowder for centuries before the Europeans, but they failed to make firearms. Had native tribes banded together to fight off the European invaders, they would have succeeded. Physical strength had nothing to do with it. Depending on the purpose of your story, you could have Neanderthal sharpshooters capable of outfighting the Spanish, or a loose collection of independent tribes which inevitably fall to the more organized invaders.

Answer (score 4):

**It’s all about the bones**

To start, Neanderthals were not a different species from modern humans, as they could successfully interbreed and Neanderthal genes live on in most non sub-Saharan  human populations. Your claim that Neanderthals would thereby be resistant to European diseases is therefore extremely unlikely, given that Europeans  have  some Neanderthal ancestry, as modern genetic testing has determined.

On the other hand, Neanderthals possessed notably shorter and thicker arm and leg bones, a wider rib cage and an otherwise more robust frame. This may have been an adaptation to the cold environments they lived in, as a stockier frame would be better at conserving heat, but this has the drawback that Neanderthals likely would be inferior long distance runners compared to modern humans. Furthermore, the correlation between brain case size and intelligence in humans is extremely weak and therefore making assumptions about intelligence based on this feature is questionable.

Neanderthal fossils have been found with numerous healed fractures, and one hypothesis about their hunting strategies was that they favored a direct and aggressive approach to killing ice age megafauna, utilizing a short sprint and burst of strength to stab animals to death with a fire hardened spear.

As for military applications, consider having the Neanderthals better at shock tactics (bayonet charges for instance) and close quarters combat, but inferior on the long march and worse as scouts and message runners

Answer (score 3):

**Humans are considered food animals.**

https://www.science.org/content/article/neanderthals-were-cannibals?

> Now anthropologists report in Science that Neanderthals living 100,000
> years ago performed precisely the same kinds of butchery on some of
> their own kind.
>
> Marks on the bones clearly reveal that these early humans filleted the
> chewing muscles from the heads of two young Neanderthals, sliced out
> the tongue of at least one, and smashed the leg bone of a large adult
> to get at the marrow. The bone fragments were apparently then dumped
> amid the remains of deer and other butchered mammals. "Human and
> mammal remains were treated very similarly," says first author Alban
> Defleur of the Université du Mediterrané at Marseilles. "We can safely
> infer that both species were exploited for a culinary goal."

The Amerinds treated Europeans more or less as people.  They communicated, traded, interbred.  Meat-hungry Neanderthals eat other hominids they don't know very well, and sometimes those that they do.  It is not a desperation move.  Just regular filling up your belly.  These weird European people who show up are just food and they are summarily butchered and made into jerky as soon as the Neanderthals realize they are there.  And it turns out Europeans are delicious!   It is hard for any colonies to get up to speed before they are eaten.